# WDIO. How to make expect compare result between two options?

Tags: node.js, webdriver-io

I have the site - https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/notification_message_rendered
By clicking on button, in upper side of site randomly appears notification either "Action successful/n×" or "Action unsuccesful, please try again\n×".
How can I get wdio expect to compare text of this notification and pass the test if notification text is either "Action successful/n×" or "Action unsuccesful, please try again\n×"?
Here is my code, I also import Chai expectation as "expectChai" to self convenient :

```
it("test comparing", async function() {
  await browser.url("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/notification_message_rendered")

  const but = await $("p > a")
  await but.click()
  const t = await $("#flash-messages > div")
  await t.waitForDisplayed()
  const tx = await t.getText()


   await expectChai(tx).to.be.equal("Action successful\n×" || "Action unsuccesful, please try again\n×")})
```

Answer (score 0):

Not strictly answer to your question but maybe could be helpful to go this way:
You get `t.getText()` and check if it match text with your element.

`expect("Action successful\n×, Action unsuccesful, please try again\n×").to.contains(tx)`

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad practice to test random values.
But ok, for me the best choice is:

```
const messages = ["Action successful\n×", "Action unsuccesful, please try again\n×"]
expectChai(tx).to.be.oneOf(messages)
```